# Magento RWD theme - Product images with gallery & lightbox option

Tags: lightbox, image-gallery, magento-1.9

As you know, new Magento RWD theme is using elevate-zoom script on product view page for zooming and switching images: [magento demo product](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/new-arrivals/khaki-bowery-chino-pants.html).

I would like to implement 'Gallery & Lightbox' option from [elevate-zoom example](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples).

I tried to edit media.phtml and app.js as well, but without luck.

Maybe someone have a solution for this?

Thanks,

Vlad

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have fancybox plugin installed together with any dependencies, i.e, mousewheel.

Best to include these in your local.xml (app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml), e.g:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.patch.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Copy app.js into your theme (maintaining directory structure) then add/edit the following:

```
image.elevateZoom({
        gallery:'gallery_01',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        galleryActiveClass: 'active',
        imageCrossfade: true,
        loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'
    });
```

Copy media.phtml into your theme (maintaining directory structure) so it uses a containing div for the gallery group immediately followed by anchor tags containing the necessary data-attributes as follows (from around line 67):

```
<div class="more-views">
    <div class="product-image-thumbs" id="gallery_01">
<?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <?php
    if (($filterClass = $this->getGalleryFilterHelper()) && ($filterMethod = $this->getGalleryFilterMethod()) && !Mage::helper($filterClass)->$filterMethod($_product, $_image)):
        continue;
    endif;
    ?>

    <?php $galImg = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(800); ?>
    <a class="thumb-link" href="#" data-image="<?php echo $galImg; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $galImg; ?>">
        <img id="img_<?php echo $i; ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>"
             width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
    </a>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

You will probably have to apply css after changing the markup within media.phtml

Comment: Tnx. I'll try and let you know if it's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct code for **app.js**

> image.bind("click", function(e) {
>         var ez = image.data('elevateZoom');
>         image.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
>         return false;
>     });

Add this after:

> image.elevateZoom();